# IntelliJ Idea IDE Detection of SQL Strings only work when SQL statement is a basic String

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I find the tightly integrated SQL statement detection in IntelliJ Idea very handy, especially when I want to perform refactoring on a table or a procedure. It will automatically go through my code and adjust the SQL query strings I have which can save me a ton of time.

The problem I am having is that when I create the String using **String.format**, it will not detect it.

Here are some examples of what it looks like when it works:

[image: Working SQL detection]
[image: Working SQL detection]

And here are some screenshots of what it looks like when it isn't detecting the SQL statements.

[image: Non-Working SQL Detection]
[image: Non-Working SQL Detection]

Notice how it colors the string when it detects that its a SQL statement and that it's just green when it does not detect that it's a SQL statement.

So when I create the string using the format method - which makes it easier to keep the strings organized and much more readable in general - Idea won't detect the string as a SQL statement, and thus it won't connect it to the tables and procedures I'm accessing which makes refactoring a pain in the arse sometimes.

Does anyone know how I can teach Idea about SQL statement detection within the **String.format** context?

Thank you,

Mike Sims

Comment: You can [add a custom pattern](https://i.imgur.com/p2TBUTg.png) in File | Settings | Editor | Language Injections to match such strings or inject SQL manually via Alt+Enter on the strings: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-injected-sql-statements.html. Does it help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder - Thank you, I have been looking everything over that you mentioned, including the JetBrains link and I've been messing with settings for about 30 minutes now and I think what might help me the most, would be if I could locate the exact setting in the IDE that causes the SQL injection with the straight forward SQL String (see my screenshot of the working example). Because I'm having a hard time determining exactly what I need to do to get this to work with the String.format method. It's not obvious to me for some reason.